# Android dialog has no focus

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have a problem about Android dialog, most of the issues appears on Samsung devices, I'm not sure whether other devices have the same problem.

When a dialog(AlertDialog or DialogFragment) is shown, it has no focus and I can't click at anything on the dialog. It seems that focus is still on activity or fragment who creates the dialog, the activity/fragment below the dialog has response to my touch events.

I use this to create a AlertDialog

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
        .setTitle(R.string.about_title)
        .setMessage(buildAppInfo())
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.app_ok, (dialog, which) -> dialog.dismiss())
        .show());
```

This is my DialogFragment class:

```
public class MyDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private MyDialogBinding binding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, android.R.style.Theme_Holo_Light_Dialog_NoActionBar_MinWidth);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.my_dialog, container, false);
        binding.tvTitle.setText(R.string.dialog_title);
        binding.tvMessage.setText(R.string.dialog_content);

        binding.btnCancel.setOnClickListener(v -> dismiss());

        return binding.getRoot();
    }


    @Override
    public void show(@NonNull FragmentManager manager, String tag) {
        if (!isAdded() && null == manager.findFragmentByTag(tag)) {
            super.show(manager, tag);
        }
    }

}
```

And use this to create a DialogFragment

```
private final MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
dialog.show(getChildFragmentManager(), "");
```

Function `setCancelableOnTouchOutside` does not work. This issue occurs sometimes, when it occurs, I have to restart my app. Thank you very much in advance for your help.

Comment: please attach the code that you are using for creating dialog.

Comment: @NoumanCh I have added my code.

Comment: you need to either use a dialog fragment or AlertDialog why you are using both codes?

Comment: @NoumanCh Both DialogFragment and AlertDialog have this issue.